# node express: print every http message to console

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having an issue with a node app I've written using express.  In order to help debug the issue, I want to print out every HTTP message that the app sends or receives to the console.  I've tried this:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req)
  console.log(res)
  next()
})
```

But the issue is the objects `res` and `req` that get printed here don't include the info I need.  They are an `HTTP.ServerResponse` and `HTTP.IncomingMessage` object, respectively.  There is no `body` element in `res` (i.e. the response my app is sending), and I can't figure out how to get it.  I've tried this as well:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var data = ''
  res.on('data', chunk => { data+=chunk })
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data)
    next()
  })
})
```

But that causes the server to hang. `next()` never gets called.

How can I do what I want?

Comment: Try to use [on-finished](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished) module. It attaches a listener to listen for the request or response to finish.

Comment: @alexmac this worked, sort of. I was able to get it to print out the response object, but I still can't figure out how to get the body of the response.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a `use` handler you absolutely must call `next` before the processing of that request continues. Here you've sabotaged yourself: You never call it until the request is finished, but that's never going to happen since you never call `next` in the first place.

What you want is probably this:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var data = ''
  res.on('data', chunk => { data+=chunk })
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data)
  })

  next()
})
```

Not calling `next` is the way you say "Wait, I'm not done yet!" but what you want is to set up those hooks and then resume processing.

Comment: I tried this, and nothing ever gets printed. I know for a fact that at least one of the responses that I'm sending has a body, so I should be seeing something. I added a debug inside the `'data'` hook, and it never gets called.

Comment: Does this hook ever get called? You should try without the path specifier to make sure it's a generic hook and not a path specific one.

Comment: the hook in general does get called every time I receive a request. I know that because the original hook prints out the entire `ServerResponse` object

Comment: I have a feeling that's a different problem. Your question pertains to it jamming up your request and preventing it from finishing. If you've got another one about hooking into the `res` and capturing data, that's a different question. Your `res` object is probably not emitting the events you think it is. That's what `req` does.

Comment: the `req` object represent the request that is received. I need to get the data for the request that is sent out. I'm trying to determine if my app is sending the wrong thing, or if the testing framework I'm using has a problem somewhere.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I think this is another question now that the `next()` issue has been resolved.